# JS function conflicting with CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a radio button part into a large form which is styled in a way that when it's hovered or checked, it has a different background color. Though, I have an important js function for the rest of the form which keeps the style from working. It took me time to understand that the conflict came from that function, but I have no clue on how to solve this.

Here's what I got:

```js
$("#general-form").on("click", "label", function() {
  name_input = $(this).children("input").attr("name");
  if (name_input) {
    onglet = obj_critere_form.simulation_encours;
    $("#simul_" + onglet + " input[name='" + name_input + "']").focus();
  }
  return false
});

obj_critere_form = new critere_form();
obj_critere_form.initialize();
```

```css
#general-form .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"],
p {
  display: none;
}

#general-form .radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#general-form .radio-toolbar label:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

#general-form .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="general-form">

  <div class="radio-toolbar">
    <h2>Options:</h2>
    </br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="a1">
    <label for="radio1">option 1</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="a2">
    <label for="radio2">option 2</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="a3">
    <label for="radio3">option 3</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without altering this function?

Comment: Is the `critere_form()` function relevant to the problem? We can't run your code without the definition.

Comment: `name_input` will always be empty with the HTML you've shown, since none of the inputs are children of the labels.

Comment: Yes, it's a function for another part of the form. If I remove it the form won't work. By removing the return false, everything seems to work fine, but I don't know if it's really the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `return false;` in the click handler. That's equivalent to `event.preventDefault();`. The default action of clicking on a label is to click on the element that the label is associated with by the `for` attribute; `return false;` prevents that from happening, so clicking on the label doesn't check the button.

I'm not sure why you have that in the click handler in the first place. All it does is prevent clicking on the label from working.

```js
$("#general-form").on("click", "label", function() {
  name_input = $(this).children("input").attr("name");
  if (name_input) {
    onglet = obj_critere_form.simulation_encours;
    $("#simul_" + onglet + " input[name='" + name_input + "']").focus();
  }
  //return false
});

//obj_critere_form = new critere_form();
//obj_critere_form.initialize();
```

```css
#general-form .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"],
p {
  display: none;
}

#general-form .radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#general-form .radio-toolbar label:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

#general-form .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="general-form">

  <div class="radio-toolbar">
    <h2>Options:</h2>
    </br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="a1">
    <label for="radio1">option 1</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="a2">
    <label for="radio2">option 2</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="a3">
    <label for="radio3">option 3</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I hope it won't affect the other parts of the form.

Comment: Maybe it should be in the `if` block? So if the label has a contained input, you focus on the element that comes from `onglet` instead of focusing on the input.

Comment: Sorry, but how to do that?

Comment: Put `return false` on the line after the call to `.focus()`, instead of the line after `}`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it looks like you're using a library for the form which could have it's own styles.

Use this at the end of the CSS you need to come through but use it sparingly and with caution.

```
//example
color: blue !important;
```

Comment: I already tried actually, but it doesn't solve this, because the conflict is on the js function.